# HeaderController is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div ng-dropdown-multiselect="" options="example1data" selected-model="example1model" events="myEventListeners"></div>      
    </div>
var app = angular.module('brandPortalApp',['angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']);
```

Hi.I am trying to create a multiselect dropdown in angularjs.When I inject ['angularjs-dropdown-multiselect'] this in angular.module i am getting an exception "Argument 'HeaderController' is not a function, got undefined".Please help:)

Header Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('brandPortalApp');
app.controller("HeaderController", ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$location', 'http_dao',
    function(rootScope, scope, location, dao) {

        scope.logout = function(){
            localStorage.removeItem("loginKey");
            rootScope.userObj = {};
            location.path("/");
        };

        scope.ads = function(){
            location.path("/dashboard/messages");
        };

        scope.visibilityMessages = function(){
            location.path("/dashboard/visibility_messages");
        };

        scope.pricePromotions = function(){
            location.path("/dashboard/price_promotions");
        }
        scope.visibility = function(){
            location.path("/dashboard/visibility");

        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: post your controller HeaderController

Comment: @Sajeetharan Please check now.Ihave posted my headerController

Comment: you have to define ng-app and ng-controller in your <div> tag.

Comment: @AnushaBayya Issue is sorted?

Comment: @Sajeetharan no I am getting the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is not with your injection, it is with the controller, Assuming **`http_dao`** is a service/factory

Change your controller as follows,

```
app.controller("HeaderController", ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$location', 'http_dao',
    function(rootScope, scope, location, http_dao) {

}
```

Also you need to pass empty dependencies to your module,

```
var app = angular.module('brandPortalApp',[]);
```

Comment: but if i remove the ['angularjs-dropdown-multiselect'] from angular.module('brandPortalApp',['angularjs-dropdown-multiselect']) then it works fine.Only after injecting it shows the error